# List of $N$ such that there is no non-zero weight 2 cusp form of level $N$

Tags: modular-forms

Is there a list of the currently known $N$ such that $S_2(\Gamma_0(N)) = {0}$?

Answer (score 6):

"Currently known" is absurd; there is an explicit formula for $\operatorname{dim} S_2(N)$ and from this it is an elementary exercise to find all such $N$. There are exactly fifteen of them, namely $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 18, 25\}$.

Comment: Yes, and more generally the formula for $S_k(\Gamma_1(N),\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is a Nebentypus is also well-known, except for $k=1$.

Comment: Does the OP assume that $N$ is an integer (rather than an ideal)?